# Expand color range selections to up or down only

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, illustrator-scripting, javascript

for example i selected some areas like following:

[image]

Now i want to expand above selections to following:

[image]

If have any trick or script for this, please provide here.
I hope you fully understand what I mean because this was the simplest possible explanation.

for example in following image i want to select all values and then convert numbers selections:
[image]

i want to tech this method to photoshop action and automate it and excute on about 500 number of images.

Comment: You don't need a script for this. You could drop some vertical and horizontal guides, and select using the rectangular marquee tool. Hold down Shift and click and drag to add to the selection.

Comment: @BillyKerr Can your method be taught to action and applied to 500 or 1000 Images? If it is possible, then post a video tutorial as an answer.

Comment: Are you trying to automate this using an action?  Then no, it won't work. Photoshop actions can't really be used to decide what to select unless every image is exactly the same. This is a manual method only.  You should mention in your question that you want to automate this, because it's not clear.

Comment: By the way, Actions can't be "taught" anything. They can only record what you do, like recording a macro. The software has no decision making capabilities.

Comment: @PubgMobile nobody is going to post a video tutorial on this site. But if you want to do this to 500 images you better add a bit more info as there s no useful info as to why you need it automated. Nor in fact any info in the post that it should be on 500 images. Anyway you might be using the wrong tool for the job. But since theres no context then theres no way to tell. So the way its asked makes it a XY problem

Comment: @joojaa post edited and added a sample of 500 number of images

Comment: Seems to me that that picture is a vector file to begin with you'd be much better of doing this in illustrator.

Comment: @joojaa which illustrator tools can do this? does illustrator have action feature?

Comment: Yes, illustrator has actions. But again your describing what your doing after step X to do Y not where you start from and where you want to end up at

Comment: In general it is better if you describe your goal, not  the intermediate steps. Why?  Because its not clear that your intermediate steps help in any way attain your goal. So start in the beginning and telll what you want in the end.

Comment: @joojaa yeah, a classic [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Reminds me a lot of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/160264). I don't understand how these crazy workflows even come about. First someone has the raw data. Then they use it to make some vector based layout. Then they export it as a raster image. Then you are to extract the raw data (or perhaps just move the numbers around and alter the design - it's unclear in your question). The real answer is "don't do it like this". Graphic design is much about choosing the right workflow. Feels strange to help people do things in the most cumbersome way possible.

Comment: @Wolff indeed, but its not without merit. just using wrong tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer but rather a long comment:

Ok, so i played with your data in mathematica, while making food, by splitting the conditioned image you have now up and text recognizing each sliver. Adjust known names so that it knows all the names your after for the fuzzy match.

```
knownNames = {"Austria-Hungary", "Belgium", "France", "German Empire",
    "Japan", "Kingdom of Italy", "Netherlands", "Ottoman Empire", 
   "Portugal", "Qing Dynasty", "Russian Empire", "Spain", "Sweden", 
   "United Kingdom", "United States"};

src = Import["C:\\temp\\temp.png"];

year = ToExpression[TextRecognize[ImageTake[src, {3680, 3950}]]];
data = Table[
   TextRecognize[
    ImageTake[src, {o, o + 130}]], {o, {760, 1000, 1220, 1430, 1640, 
     1840, 2030, 2210, 2390, 2580, 2750, 2920, 3080, 3240, 3380}}];

conditionedData = StringDelete[data, {"  ", ","}];
mathcedName = Flatten[Nearest[knownNames, conditionedData, 1]];
conditionedNumber = 
  Table[ToExpression[Last[StringSplit[i, " "]]], {i , 
    conditionedData}];
onePagesData = 
 Transpose[{mathcedName, Table[year, {i, 15}], conditionedNumber}]
```

Which gives me:

```
{
{"Qing Dynasty", 1874, 905666},
{"Russian Empire", 1874, 828331}, 
{"France", 1874, 524000}, 
{"German Empire", 1874, 426500}, 
{"Austria-Hungary", 1874, 290833},
{"United Kingdom", 1874, 251333},
{"Kingdom of Italy", 1874, 163667},
{"Ottoman Empire", 1874, 149061},
{"Spain", 1874, 100500}, 
{"Sweden", 1874, 68333}, 
{"United States", 1874,  43167}, 
{"Belgium", 1874, 42716}, 
{"Japan", 1874, 40167}, 
{"Netherlands", 1874, 39860}, 
{"Portugal", 1874, 36167}
}
```

This can be then put to graph generation code, or appended to a csv file, which is not all that big of a deal, but now the food is ready to come out from oven.

Addendum:

```
BarChart[Reverse[onePagesData[[All, 3]]], Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> False, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLabels ->
  Placed[Reverse[onePagesData[[All, 1]]], Before], 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, After] &),
 BarSpacing -> 1,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ImageSize -> 600,
 ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[None]},
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Pastel"]
 ]
```

Results in (here as png, but could be exported as fully vector PDF):
[image]
Stylize to your hearts content. Alternatively put it to your animation software.

You could swap mathematica to image magic and some command line text recognition code + some batch, or python. Should be semi easy. Just your using wrong tool for the job.

Comment: PS: if i can get a original frame im pretty sure one can sidestep much of your conditioning so far. Things is as i alluded, there is no value in thinking about the steps you spent time on. Just think about the future investment.